# Is there a way to remove the number of rows in a row group in AG grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'd like to hide the number of rows being grouped- the number is shown in the image
[image: image:]
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In grid options, add this parameter

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
  cellRendererParams: {
    suppressCount: true,
  },
},
```

Here's an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/OZ48nG4OIvyk762k?preview